why openCV is not found by cmake when using vcpkg in manifest mode?
I have this cmake file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

File(TO_CMAKE_PATH $ENV{VCPKG_ROOT} VCPKG_ROOT)
message(STATUS ${VCPKG_ROOT})
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" CACHE STRING "")
set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x64-windows-static" CACHE STRING "")

project(my_project)


find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

set(INCLUDE_DIR "src/include" )  
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIR})

# Set C++ standard to 20
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

file(GLOB_RECURSE  INCLUDE_FILES  "src/include/*.h" "src/include/*.hpp") 


add_executable(ReadSample "src/readsample/main.cpp" ${INCLUDE_FILES})
set_property(TARGET ReadSample PROPERTY
             MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>")
# Include directories for header files
target_link_libraries(ReadSample ${OpenCV_LIBS})

and vcpkg.json is:
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": [
        {
            "name": "opencv",
            "features": [
                "ffmpeg"
      ]
    }
    ]
}

when I am trying to build the project, I can see that vcpkg is building opencv in my build directory, but then I am getting this error:
 D:/Local/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:859 (_find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)

Why vcpkg can not find openCV?

Is that the full error output?

so you're saying cmake can't find OpenCV? where does cmake look for the FindOpenCV.cmake file? is the file there?

@ChristophRackwitz vcpkg should be setting that up

then I guess that might be the issue. I don't know vcpkg at all.
